# Access public enum from inner class

Tags: java, enums

I have an `enum` defined in a file `State.java`:

```
public enum State {
  NONE, CHOOSINGMUD, PLAYING
}
```

I have a public class `Server` from which I can access the enum with `State.NONE` and this works fine.

However, within `Server` I have a public inner class defined, and when I try to acces `State.NONE` there, I get a `cannot find symbol error`:

```
  symbol:   variable State
  location: class Server
```

How do I use `State` from within this inner class? Is it possible to do so directly like I do inside my `Server` class? It seems to me like it's looking for `State` inside it's parent class (`Server`).

Here is the code for my inner class. I've simplified it, but the print statement here will return the same error:

```
  public class ClientConnection extends Thread
  {
   private PlayerInterface player;

   ClientConnection(PlayerInterface player) throws IOException
   {
    this.player = player;
    System.out.println(State.NONE);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the inner class?

Comment: I've posted the inner class, hope that helps.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can make the inner class static.

Comment: you might be conflicting with the State object in threading.. it has no NONE property... there are many objects called State, make sure it's yours look at your import statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `State` class is conflicting with inner class `java.lang.Thread.State` which does not have a `NONE` field. Rename your enum class to something else and your code will work

Comment: He should be fine if he uses the absolute path to the enum instead of just State.None. Probably easier if he does not intend to change the name of the enumerator

Comment: And this is why one must always define a package and not use the default one.

Comment: @Saraiva I prefer renaming - avoids any possible confusion later :)

Comment: I did define a package, but just once in the parent of the inner class. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dylan, the enum should also be in a package (probably the same package). If it was, you would have been able to access it using the package name.

Comment: @RealSkeptic   Ah I see, good to know. I did have State in the same package, but didn't know about accessing it with the package name. I've just renamed the class instead to avoid confusion but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a file with this in it

```
public enum State {
  on, off
}
```

then a file with this in it

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static class SomeInnerClass{
   State s = State.off;
    public void doSomething(State state){
      if(state == State.off){
        //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

seems to work fine. I can access it at the inner class's class level and in a method. Hope looking at this helps

Comment: Just curious: why would creating separate files work? Thanks.

Comment: The op already has separate files, same as above. I did what the op is doing, just to show that it actually should work, so there is something else wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this does work but unfortunately I can't make my inner class static for other reasons.

Comment: @dylan it works whether static or not... i tried that too out of curiosity

Comment: @Unheilig The fact that it works has nothing to do with the files. It has to be in two separate files because both classes are public. But this one works because there is no naming conflicts with `State`, unlike the OP's situation.

Comment: It seems it was conflicting with another State class per Reimeus' answer. I tried that code in a fresh project and it worked for me as well, but I think the issue was that my class was extending Thread. Thanks for the help though!